# How to revert Application.Volatile?

Tags: vba, excel

When I started to code my Excel tool, I defined a function as `Application.Volatile` because I wanted it to recalculate each time a value was changed in the spreadsheet :

```
Function myFunction()
    Application.Volatile
    'body of my function
End Function
```

Once my code got complex, I realized that this function being volatile was called millions of times when executing, slowing down violently the performance of the tool.

I hence decided to take it down and make it not volatile. 
However, I've tried:

1. To just remove the `Application.Volatile` from the function, and still when I was changing one parameter the function was recalculating --> this was probably expected as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/en-en/library/office/ff195441.aspx), once I say `Application.Volatile` I give a `True` value by default in parameter.
2. As described on the documentation above, I tried to explicitly write in the body of my function `Application.Volatile False`. Still, no chance.

I have tried to close down Excel, re-compile the code, no chance: my function doesn't want to stop being Volatile. 
Can anyone please help me to understand where the problem is?

Comment: Can you repro if you copy the function in a new, empty workbook?

Comment: @Mat'sMug will try to do that tomorrow when back at work, and will add a test case if I manage to reproduce.

Comment: For everyone wondering why ```Application.Volatile False``` isn't working, you probaly left ```Application.Volatile``` at the top any other function.